# Is it necessary to validate an encrypted password server side?

Tags: node.js, regex, validation, express, bcrypt

I am building a node.js web application using Express and React and was wondering if it is necessary to validate a password encrypted using bcrypt as follows:

```
bcrypt.genSalt(10, (err, salt) => {
  bcrypt.hash(newUser.password, salt, (err, hash) => {
    if (err) {throw err;}
    newUser.password = hash;
    newUser
      .save()
      .then(user => res.json(user))
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
    });
  });
```

I'm validating the password on the client side using this regex:

```
(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,}
```

As far as I understand, client side validation is not enough because attackers can inject using other methods. So is it necessary for me to validate the password server side as well? If so, should I be validating the encrypted password? Or should I validate the password using the above regex again before I encrypt it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Basically password validation sucks and it generally counter productive. If the password is protecting the user let the user select and only do one thing (if any) of deleting invisible characters. If you are protecting the server that validation is not sufficient. See appendix A of [NIST Digital Identity Guidelines](http://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/SpecialPublications/NIST.SP.800-63b.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

Encrypting a password is necessary for the security of your users. When you use bcrypt, you're actually storing a hash of the password in your database.

Let's say a user wants to log in. Username: me Password: mypassword1.

If a user puts that in a login page, and you're not validating the hash of the user's password against the hash stored in the database, any user can put any password and be given the authorization to be that user.

If you're worried about XSS injections; follow the basic rule of thumb - don't trust the client. Therefore, always validate against all inputs before passing it to the server. The server (or API) should also validate against this just in case a malicious user will bypass your client and just hit your endpoints using curl, postman, or any other tool used to make HTTP requests.

Comment: So should I validate the unencrypted password on the server?

Comment: Absolutely! The client is never secure